# Book about a girl who drains your life upon touching you, is hunted by a group which wants to weaponize her

Tags: story-identification, novel, books

There was a book I read but I can't remember the name of it; I think it was "Shattered" something.

It was about a girl who drained your life upon touching you. It was set in the future and there was a group controlling everything that wanted her to be a weapon, and she refused.

In the beginning she was in an asylum and they sent an undercover soldier to see how sane she was. He turned out to be someone from her childhood and her curse/gift didn't work on him and they fell in love and escaped.

It was a part of a series but that was the only one I read.

Comment: Hi there! Maybe you could [edit] in roughly when you read that? Was it in English, was it a translation? What did the cover look like? Stuff like that, to increase the chances of a successful ID.

Comment: One of these, possibly; http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/adv_search_results.cgi?USE_1=title_title&OPERATOR_1=starts_with&TERM_1=shattered&CONJUNCTION_1=AND&USE_2=title_title&OPERATOR_2=exact&TERM_2=&CONJUNCTION_2=AND&USE_3=title_title&OPERATOR_3=exact&TERM_3=&ORDERBY=title_title&START=0&TYPE=Title

Answer (score 6):

This is the [Shatter Me series](http://shatterme.wikia.com/wiki/Shatter_Me_Series).

> Juliette hasn't touched anyone in exactly 264 days.
>   The last time she did, it was an accident, but The Reestablishment locked her up for murder. No one knows why Juliette's touch is fatal. As long as she doesn't hurt anyone else, no one really cares. The world is too busy crumbling to pieces to pay attention to a 17-year-old girl. Diseases are destroying the population, food is hard to find, birds don't fly anymore, and the clouds are the wrong color.
>   The Reestablishment said their way was the only way to fix things, so they threw Juliette in a cell. Now so many people are dead that the survivors are whispering war-- and The Reestablishment has changed its mind. Maybe Juliette is more than a tortured soul stuffed into a poisonous body. Maybe she's exactly what they need right now.
>   Juliette has to make one difficult choice: To be a weapon, or a warrior.